# C++ Visual 2019 error const char incompatible

Tags: c++, char, constants

I get this error :

```
Das Argument vom Typ ""const char *"" ist mit dem Parameter vom Typ ""char *"" inkompatibel.
```

The argument from type `const char` is with the parameter from type `char` incompatible.

```
Animal::Animal(const char* k )
{
    next = 0;
    kind = new char[strlen(k) + 1];
    strcpy(kind,k);
}
```

Comment: What is `kind`? How do you construct your `Animal`? On which line do you get the error? Try to provide a minimal-reproducible example of the error you see.

Comment: Maybe you declared `const char* kind;` inside `Animal` class? Remove the `const`.

Comment: If allowed, discard the `char *` and manual memory management in favour of a `std::string`. Having to manage the allocation at `kind` yourself increases the complexity and amount of code you have to write code greatly. If the manual management is a requirement, read up on [The Rule of Three (and friends)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). `std::string` observes the Rule of Five, allowing your code to observe the Rule of Zero.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if the `kind` data member is defined as type `const char *`:

```
  error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
```

Defining the `kind` data member of type `char *` solves the problem:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class Animal
{
    public:
        Animal(const char *k)
        {
            next = 0;
            kind = new char[strlen(k) + 1];
            strcpy(kind, k);
        }
        
        const char* getKind() const
        {
            return kind;
        }
    private:
        int next;
        char *kind; /* The kind data member is defined as type "const *". */
};

int main()
{
    const char *k = "Cat";
    Animal animal(k);
    cout << "Kind: " << animal.getKind() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Kind: Cat
```

Comment: Thanks i solved it ;)

Comment: Note that this answer leaves out some important pieces not relevant to the question as asked. As a result it leaks memory. Understand the example, its purpose, and the portions omitted before using the code.